# Scope of boolean variable

Tags: python-3.x

The following code producing - `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ws_is_connected' referenced before assignment`:

```
import threading

ws_is_connected=False
def timer_ws():
    threading.Timer(22.0, timer_ws).start()
    if not ws_is_connected:
        print("Alarm")
        ws_is_connected=False
    print("22 seconds")
    
timer_ws()
```

For some reason a Python thinks that this variable a local, but it was declared globally on top. I am newbie in Python, so maybe doing something wrong.

The reason the `ws_is_connected` settled lower is a websocket client ping-pong check. I need to reset this variable every 22 seconds in order to make sure that ws connection is alive:

```
def on_pong(ws, message):
    print("Got a pong! No need to respond")
    ws_is_connected=True
```

Cause on_pong function repeats every 10 seconds.

I am looking for some way to modify a code so it will work or use another approach and rewrite code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the function use the global variable as well. Just before calling the variable in the function, add `global var_name` and it should work fine like this:

```
def timer_ws():
    threading.Timer(22.0, timer_ws).start()
    global ws_is_connected
    if not ws_is_connected:
```

Comment: I think now I understand how `global` is working.